# pandas count possible combinations of column values based on conditions per id

Tags: python, pandas

Let's assume such dataset

```
data=[['id1','bla bla word1', 10], ['id1','bla bla word2', 12], ['id1','bla bla', 10], ['id2','bla bla', 10], ['id2','bla bla bla123', 11] , ['id3','bla bla word1', 22],\
      ['id4','bla bla word1', 22], ['id4','bla bla nicebla', 2], ['id5','bla bla word2', 22], ['id5','bla bla word2', 22], ['id6','bla bla word2', 22],['id6','bla bla bla22', 112],\
     ['id7','bla bla word2', 17],['id7','bla bla word1', 19]]
df_test=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'search_word', 'value'])
```

so the df output:

```
    id  search_word value
0   id1 bla bla word1   10
1   id1 bla bla word2   12
2   id1 bla bla 10
3   id2 bla bla 10
4   id2 bla bla bla123  11
5   id3 bla bla word1   22
6   id4 bla bla word1   22
7   id4 bla bla nicebla 2
8   id5 bla bla word2   22
9   id5 bla bla word2   22
10  id6 bla bla word2   22
11  id6 bla bla bla22   112
12  id7 bla bla word2   17
13  id7 bla bla word1   19
```

My task is to count how many records have different possible combinations, so in other words count ids with possible combinations, which are based on the conditions.
The combinations(and conditions) are:
group1 - ids containing rows with either word 1 or word2 in the search_word column -so in the example should be only rows with id7 
group2 -ids containing rows with either word 1 or word2 and other words() so result should be only rows with id1
group3-ids containing only word1:result id3 row
group4-ids containing only word1 and other:result id4 rows
group5-ids containing only word2:result id5 rows
group6-ids containing only word2 and other: result id6 rows
group7-ids containing only other words than word1 or word2:result id2 rows
I tried to accomplish this task by such approach:
for example for the first group1

```
df_test[(df_test['search_word'].str.contains('word1|word2')).groupby(df_test["id"]).transform('all')]
```

It outputs too many values:

```
    id  search_word value
5   id3 bla bla word1   22
8   id5 bla bla word2   22
9   id5 bla bla word2   22
12  id7 bla bla word2   17
13  id7 bla bla word1   19
```

but works for groups 3 and 5:

group3

```
df_test[((df_test['search_word'].str.contains('word1')) & (~df_test['search_word'].str.contains('word2'))).groupby(df_test["id"]).transform('all')]

    id  search_word value
5   id3 bla bla word1   22
```

and group5 will be covered by:

```
df_test[((df_test['search_word'].str.contains('word2')) & (~df_test['search_word'].str.contains('word1'))).groupby(df_test["id"]).transform('all')]

    id  search_word value
8   id5 bla bla word2   22
9   id5 bla bla word2   22
```

so my question is how to accomplish the overall task , it there any other unified way to cover those different possibilities?

Comment: *group1 - ids containing rows with either word 1 or word2 in the search_word column -so in the example should be only rows with id7.* Should this be word 1 AND word2? Otherwise why is id7 only matching when id1 contains word1?

Comment: As I wrote , I need to count every combination of records having for the same id word1 , word2 and other not containg either word1 or word2 , so id1 in this case has different combination than id7